# React, el estado demora en actualizarse

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Al actualizar el estado y entrar en la funcion verifyStatus y ver el valor del objeto firstChosen esta el valor por anterior al que se eleasigno al actualizar pero al entrar por segunda es decir al dar dos clicks ya entra y tiene el valor deseado; la conclusion a la que llego es que el estado entra en cola a actualizarse pero lo hace una ves que sale ya de la funcion verifyStatus no se como hacerlo antes, ya prove con async y await y tampoco funciono, si alguien sabe algo muchas gracias

```
const verifyStatus=(id)=>{
    console.log(firstChosen);
    console.log(secondChosen);
    if(firstChosen["selected"] && secondChosen["selected"]){
        console.log("Entro");
        if(firstChosen["tipo"]===secondChosen["tipo"]){
            let auxCoins=[...coins];
            const coinIndex = coins.findIndex(coin => coin.id===id);
            auxCoins[coinIndex].selected=true;
            setCantidadCoins(cantidadCoins+2);
            setCoinsArray(auxCoins)
        }else{
            let auxCoins=[...coins];
            const coinIndex1 = coins.findIndex(coin => coin.id===firstChosen["id"]);
            const coinIndex2 = coins.findIndex(coin => coin.id===secondChosen["id"]);
            auxCoins[coinIndex1].selected=false;
            auxCoins[coinIndex2].selected=false;
            setCoinsArray(auxCoins)
        }
        setSecondChosen({id:-1,tipo:0,selected:false})
        setFirstChosen({id:-1,tipo:0,selected:false})
    }else{
        let auxCoins=[...coins];
        const coinIndex = coins.findIndex(coin => coin.id===id);
        auxCoins[coinIndex].selected=true;
        setCoinsArray(auxCoins)
    }
    if(coins.every(coin=>coin.selected===true)){
        setTimeout(siguienteNivel,3000);
    }
}
const selectedCoin=(id)=>{
    if(firstChosen["selected"]){
        let coinIndexAux = coins.findIndex(coin => coin.id===id);
        setSecondChosen({id:id,tipo:coins[coinIndexAux].tipo,selected:true})
    }else{
        let coinIndexAux2 = coins.findIndex(coin => coin.id===id);
        setFirstChosen({id:id,tipo:coins[coinIndexAux2].tipo,selected:true})            
    }
    verifyStatus(id);
}
```

Comment: Estoy seguro que tu problema tiene que ver con lo que se explica en el siguiente articulo: [Dentro de la caja negra de “setState”](https://desarrollos-web-urquiza.medium.com/dentro-de-la-caja-negra-de-setstate-69001c7c6ea4). Al leerlo, entederás la raíz de tu problema y de seguro encontrarás su solución.